# Build Failed in Azure devops

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm beginner for this in azure devops.
I'm trying to build with maven, but I got the following error that I don't understand :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:instrument (package-9af52907-6506-4b87-b16a-9883edee41bc) on project gs-spring-boot: Execution package-9af52907-6506-4b87-b16a-9883edee41bc of goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:instrument failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: try to maven build locally and see if the build succeeds. if it doesn't, it's not related to Azure and needs be fixed locally first

Answer (score 0):

You are missing tools.jar in your JDK/JRE. Make sure your JDK version on Azure Pipeline. It seems Cobertura doesn't support Java 1.8 and later:

- https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/30
- https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/21

So, switch to [JaCoCo](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html).